# Is this a correct recurrence relationship I've found for the coin change challenge?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, tree, time-complexity

I'm trying to solve the "coin change problem" and I think I've come up with a recursive solution but I want to verify.

As a a example, let's suppose we have pennies, nickles and dimes and are trying to make change for 22 cents.

```
C = { 1 = penny, nickle = 5, dime = 10 }
K = 22
```

Then the number of ways to make change is

```
f(C,N) = f({1,5,10},22) 
=
  (# of ways to make change with 0 dimes) 
+ (# of ways to make change with 1 dimes) 
+ (# of ways to make change with 2 dimes) 

= f(C\{dime},22-0*10) + f(C\{dime},22-1*10) + f(C\{dime},22-2*10)
= f({1,5},22) + f({1,5},12) + f({1,5},2)
```

and

```
  f({1,5},22) 
= f({1,5}\{nickle},22-0*5) + f({1,5}\{nickle},22-1*5) + f({1,5}\{nickle},22-2*5) + f({1,5}\{nickle},22-3*5) + f({1,5}\{nickle},22-4*5)
= f({1},22) + f({1},17) + f({1},12) + f({1},7) + f({1},2)
= 5
```

and so forth.

In other words, my algorithm is like

```
let f(C,K) be the number of ways to make change for K cents with coins C
and have the following implementation

if(C is empty or K=0)
    return 0
sum = 0
m = C.PopLargest()
A = {0, 1, ..., K / m}
for(i in A)
   sum += f(C,K-i*m)
return sum
```

If there any flaw in that?

Would be linear time, I think.

Comment: Is  my answer helpful for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Rethink about your base cases:

```
1. What if K < 0 ? Then no solution exists. i.e. No of ways = 0.

2. When K = 0, so there is 1 way to make changes and which is to consider zero elements from array of coin-types. 

3. When coin array is empty then No of ways = 0.
```

Rest of the logic is correct. But your perception that the algorithm is Linear is absolutely wrong.

Lets compute the complexity:

- Popping largest element is O(C.length). However this step can be
  optimised if you consider sorting the whole array in the beginning.
- Your for Loop works O(K/C.max) times in every call and in every iteration it is calling the function recursively.

So if you write the recurrence for it. then it should be something like:

```
T(N) = O(N) + K*T(N-1)
```

And this is going to be exponential in terms of N (Size of array).

In case you are looking for improvement, i would suggest you to use Dynamic Programming.